# Java String split without any delimiter

Tags: java, string

Want to split String given as "BhilaiPuneBanglore" into 3 different string.
can any one help on this?

Comment: What's your logic for splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "BhilaiPuneBanglore";
String[] arr = str.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");

for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

`\p{Upper}   An upper-case alphabetic character:[A-Z]`, split uses it as delimiter. For more check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

You can use `String[] arr = str.split("(?=[A-Z])");`

**Output**

```
Bhilai
Pune
Banglore
```

Comment: thanks Aniruddha this might help for further logic in the question that i hav.... :-) once again thanx alot...